# 301 redirects htaccess configuration

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a website Drupal to Wordpress conversion for a client, and the site has a LOT of content. Over 300 pages, and 750 blog posts.

I'm looking for a .htaccess 301 redirect for the blog posts, but doing 750 different 301 redirections seems horribly inefficient. I'm already biting the bullet for the 300 pages.

Is there a rewrite rule I can utilize to rewrite the following url?

```
Redirect 301 http://website.org/blog/YYYY/MM/DD/Post-title 

to http://website.org/blog/Post-title/
```

The dates go from 2016 to 2008.

Before I invest several hours into the per url basis, I want to see if there is a rewrite condition/rule I can utilize.

Thanks!

Comment: This is the perfect problem for a regular expression. I highly recommend learning them if you program at all. The O'Reilly book Mastering Regular Expressions is great if you want a very thorough guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)?$ /blog/$4 [R=301,L]
```

This matches "4 digits/2 digits/2 digits/whatever" and rewrites such requests to "/blog/whatever".

Comment: Wow. If this works...You are the programming lunchtime hero! :)

If i were to want to add a trailing slash at the end, all I do is add a / after $4?

Comment: Ah. I made a blunder, fixing the initial post. 

    http://website.org/blog/YYYY/MM/DD/post-title
    to http://website.org/blog/post-title

:/

Comment: Am i correct by removing /blog from the rewrite rule since it already exists? 

so it would be:

    RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4}/(0-9){2}/(0-9){2}/(.*)?$ /$4 [R=301,l]
?

Comment: With slash at the beginning it will redirect to yoursite.com/post-title. You may get an odd redirect if you leave just `$4`. If you are putting the .htaccess file into /blog directory, then it should work out of the box.

Comment: Okay, so a site can have multiple .htaccess files in various directories, being a wordpress site, the default generated wordpress file contained some code.

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)?$ /$4 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Is there anything I need to remove from here to achieve the desired result? or is it good as-is. I suspect its okay,but verification helps

Comment: what if i do

RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)?$ /blog/$4 [R=301,L]

Comment: `RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)?$ /blog/$4 [R=301,L]` should be in your website's root directory and it should work that way. Also, since you've abandoned WP, I guess that /blog directory does not exist any more, or just rename it if it exists, so it does not interfere with rewrite rules.

Comment: An Update, The code had to be modified a little bit before it was fully working.

The End Result `RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)?$ /bas/blog/$4 [R=301,L]`

/bas/ is the directory the site is in, but can be removed if you have a site in the base url. Very elegant, saved me tons of time. Thanks Guys!